# How can I format multiple tables to be in proportion?

Tags: tables, formatting, tabularx, threeparttable, ltablex

I'm trying to create an Appendix of SPSS tables in APA6 (12 pt) format.

The issue is that some of the tables are greater than the width of the page. Any way I can think of to shrink them scales them down such that the text size is different in each table, which looks messy and is hard to read.

I've tried adjustbox around 2 tables but they end up next to each other, and I've since read adjustbox isn't good for tables. I've tried to play around with xltabular, tabular*, tabularx but I haven't been able to make them work for my scenario, and I think the solution is probably beyond me.

If anyone could show me how to do this it would be a huge help.

````
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{adjustbox}


\begin{document}

\section{Appendix}


\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{tabular}{llllll}
\toprule
                     & Colour & N  & Mean   & Std. Deviation & Std. Error Mean \\
                     \midrule
  Attractive average & Grey         & 26 & 5.2051 & 1.47897        & .29005          \\
                     & Red        & 17 & 5.1569 & 2.00734        & .48685          \\
                     \bottomrule
     
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\bigskip
\begin{table}[!]
\textwidth
\begin{tabular}{0}{lllllllllll}
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Levene's Test for Equality of Variances} & \multicolumn{7}{c}{t-test for Equality of Means} \\
& F  & Sig. & t & df   & Sig. (2-tailed) & MD & Std. ED & \multicolumn{2}{c}{95\% CI of the Difference} \\
     &   &  &    &      &      &      &  & Lower & Upper    \\
\midrule
  Attractive average & Equal variances assumed  
  & 5.856 & .020    & .091 & 41 & .928 & .04827& .53172 & -1.02557 & 1.12210 \\
 & Equal variances not assumed   &       &   & .085 & 27.182          & .933 & .04827 & .56670 & -1.11415 & 1.21068 \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{adjustbox}{width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{l l l l l l l l l l l }
\toprule
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Levene's Test for Equality of Variances} & \multicolumn{7}{c}{t-test for Equality of Means} \\
& F  & Sig. & t & df   & Sig. (2-tailed) & MD & Std. ED & \multicolumn{2}{c}{95\% CI of the Difference} \\
     &   &  &    &      &      &      &  & Lower & Upper    \\
\midrule
  Attractive average & Equal variances assumed  
  & 5.856 & .020    & .091 & 41 & .928 & .04827& .53172 & -1.02557 & 1.12210 \\
 & Equal variances not assumed   &       &   & .085 & 27.182          & .933 & .04827 & .56670 & -1.11415 & 1.21068 \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}```
````

Comment: The usual approach is to set the font size (\small, \footnotesize, \scriptsize, \tiny) which can be done for the entire appendix.  The second choice is to use landscape.  After that, things get nasty.

Comment: Allowing linebreaks inside of table cells can also help to reduce the overall width of a table.

Comment: Thankyou both, I've decreased the font size and added some line breaks and it's looking much better!

Comment: Unrelated to the issue: Currently, the last column in your third table does not have a column header. Is that intentional or are the headers just shifted to the left?